# How to infinity spin on slot machine jQuery and stop it after do some action?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 option in radio input

1. Tab screen to stop in 0.5 sec -> So I complete this solution.
2. Tab screen to stop immediately. I want it spin after I press the submit button and it stops after I tab the screen.

Here is my fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/7det89o6/3/

```js
$("#submit-btn").click(function() {
  var cond = valRadioFunc();

  if (cond == 1) {
    $('.reel-container:first').slotMachine('00' + 1).toString();
      // one click
      $(".bg-img").one("click", function() {
        $('.reel-container:first').slotMachine(randGen());
      });
    } else if (cond == 2) {
      $('.reel-container:first').slotMachine('00' + 1).toString();
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
<script type="text/javascript">

            var reeling_time = 500;
            var stop_spinning_time_difference = 350;
            var start_spinning_time = 0;
            var currency_symbol = "$";
            var isInfinity = false;

            $(document).ready(function() {

                $(document).on('show.bs.modal', '.modal', function() {


                    function valRadioFunc() {
                        var valRadio = $('input[name=radio]:checked', '#form-select').val();
                        return valRadio;
                    }

                    $("#submit-btn").click(function() {

                        var cond = valRadioFunc();
                        if (cond == 1) {
                            $('.reel-container:first').slotMachine('00' + 1).toString();
                            // one click
                            $(".bg-img").one("click", function() {
                                isInfinity = false;
                                $('.reel-container:first').slotMachine(randGen());
                            });

                        } else if (cond == 2) {
                            $('.reel-container:first').slotMachine('00' + 1).toString();
                            isInfinity = true;
                            // one click
                            $(".bg-img").one("click", function() {
                                reeling_time = 0;
                                isInfinity = false;
                                $('.reel-container:first').slotMachine(randGen());
                            });
                        }
                    });

                });

            });


            function randGen() {
                var minRange = 1;
                var maxRange = 999;
                var randNum = (Math.floor(Math.random() * maxRange) + minRange).toString();
                if (randNum.toString().length == 3) {
                    return randNum;
                } else if (randNum.toString().length == 2) {
                    return "0" + randNum;
                } else if (randNum.toString().length == 1) {
                    reeling_time = 0;
                    return "00" + randNum;
                }
            }

        function collision($div1, $div2) {
            var x1 = $div1.offset().left;
            var w1 = 40;
            var r1 = x1 + w1;
            var x2 = $div2.offset().left;
            var w2 = 40;
            var r2 = x2 + w2;

            if (r1 < x2 || x1 > r2) return false;
            return true;

        }


        $.fn.slotMachine = function(my_number) {

            var $parentSlot = this;
            var hidden_reels_html = '';
            var hidden_reels_array = [];
            var numberFormat = function number_format(number) {
                number = (number + '');
                return number;
            }

            for (var $j = 0; $j <= 9; $j++) {
                hidden_reels_array[$j] = "";
                for (var $i = 0; $i <= 9; $i++) {
                    hidden_reels_array[$j] += '<div class="reel-symbol' + ($i == 0 ? ' reel-loop' : '') + '">' + (($j + $i) % 10) + '</div>';
                }
            }

            var transformNumberToArrayPlusDollar = function(my_number) {
                var my_scale = parseInt(my_number, 10) > 999 ? 0 : 2;

                my_number = numberFormat(my_number, my_scale, ".", ",");

                var my_number_array = my_number.split('');

                // my_number_array.unshift(currency_symbol);

                return my_number_array;
            };

            //Effect for the reel to go up and then down like it is pushed to spin
            var effectBeforeSpin = function() {
                $parentSlot.find('.main-reel-symbol').removeClass('reel-stop').addClass('reel-begin');
            };

            var slotMachine = function(my_number) {

                var my_number_array = transformNumberToArrayPlusDollar(my_number);
                var reels_html = '';

                for (var $i = 0; $i < my_number_array.length; $i++) {
                    reels_html += '<div class="reel">' + hidden_reels_array[($i % 10)] + '</div>';
                }

                effectBeforeSpin();

                var startSpinning = function() {

                    $parentSlot.html(reels_html);

                    var my_timer = reeling_time;

                    $.each(my_number_array, function(my_index, my_value) {

                        var next_value = /^[0-9]$/.test(my_value) ? (parseInt(my_value, 10) + 1) % 10 : "0";

                        var stopSpinning = function() {
                        
                            $parentSlot.find('.reel:eq(' + my_index + ')')
                                .html("<div class='reel-symbol main-reel-symbol reel-stop'>" + my_value + "</div>")
                                .append("<div class='reel-symbol'>" + next_value + "</div>");
                        };

                        if(!isInfinity){
                            setTimeout(stopSpinning, my_timer);
                        }
                        my_timer += stop_spinning_time_difference;
                    });

                };

                setTimeout(startSpinning, start_spinning_time);
            };

            slotMachine(my_number);

            return this;

        };

        $('.reel-container:first').slotMachine('00' + 1).toString();

</script>
```

I add one variable at top of JavaScript code.

Comment: Thank you so much you save my life ^^

Comment: Hello can I custom the reeling time when I chose the option 1